# handle json file csharp console

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have local Json file , and i want to handle it . so delete , create
   , change value , and getall.

SO , its my json example

```
[   {
   "Alerts": {
     "Name": "RoseDeal",
     "Description": "Problème au sein de Rosedeal",
     "StartDate": "2017-07-17T00:00:00",
     "EndDate": "2008-07-19T00:00:00",
     "Niveau": "Urgent",
     "Type": "Girophare",
     "Id": 1
   }   } ]
```

i work in a console program just for try .

```
public bool DeleleAlert(int alertId )
{                 
    var filePath = @"C:\Users\korben\Documents\Visual Studio       2017\Projects\SaveFiles\SaveFiles\json\alerts.json";
    string Json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    var alerts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Alert>>(Json);
    var newJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(alerts.Where(i =>   i.Id != alertId));
    return true;
}


public bool SaveAlert(Alert newAlert)
{
    var filePath = @"C:\Users\korben\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SaveFiles\SaveFiles\json\alerts.json";
    string Json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    dynamic contourManifest = JObject.Parse(Json);
    foreach (var Alerts in contourManifest.features)
    {
      Alerts.Name.Replace( JObject.FromObject(new { Name = Alerts.Name["SANG"] }));
    }

    var newJson = contourManifest.ToString();

// Missing a closing brace here?

public Alert GetAlert(int alertId)
{
   List<Alert> alerts;
   // Lire le fichier JSON 
   alerts = ReadFile();
   // Rechercher l'alerte demandé via sont ID
   var myAlert = alerts.Where(a => a.Id == alertId).FirstOrDefault();
   return myAlert;
}

} } // <-- ?

public void CreateALert(List<AlertObject> alerts)
{
      var filePath = @"C:\Users\korben\Documents\Visual Studio             2017\Projects\SaveFiles\SaveFiles\json\alerts.json";
      string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(alerts, Formatting.Indented);
      File.WriteAllText(filePath, json); 
}
} // <-- ?
```

Its not all my code but only creation , GetAlert work. delete and
savealert (change value) don't work and I don't understand why . 
Here's the program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
       int count = 0;
       var myAlert = new List<Alert>();
       var myAlertObject = new List<AlertObject>();
       AlertObject oAlertObject = new AlertObject();
       var newAlert = new Alert
       {
           Name = "RoseDeal",
           Description = "Problème au sein de Rosedeal",
           StartDate = new DateTime(2017, 7, 17),
           EndDate = new DateTime(2008, 7, 19),
           Niveau = "Urgent",
           Type = "Girophare",
           Id = ++count,
       };

       oAlertObject.OAlert = newAlert;
       myAlertObject.Add(oAlertObject);
       Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
       JsonAlert rene = new JsonAlert();
       rene.CreateALert(myAlertObject);
       rene.GetAlert(1);
       //rene.SaveAlert(newAlert);
       rene.DeleleAlert(1);
 }
 } // <-- ?
```

Comment: What are the class definitions for `Alert` and `AlertObject`?  Also when you say that `Delete` and `SaveAlert` "don't work" what do you mean by that?  Do you get an exception?  Does it do nothing?  In other words, what are you expecting it to do and what does it actually do (or not do) instead?

Comment: I tried to reformat your code, but your braces just don't line up. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it like this:

```
public class Alert //This is each alert
{
    public string Name;
    public string Decription;
    ...
}

public class Alerts //This is group of all alert
{
    public List<Alert> Alert;

    public Alerts()
    {
        Alert = new List<Alert>();
    }
}

public class Program
{        
    public static Alerts LoadAlertsFromJson() //With this you can load alerts to other classes with Program.LoadAlertsFromJson();
    {
        string jsonString = loadYourStringHere;
        Alerts a = JsonUtility.FromJson<Alerts>(jsonString);
        return a;
    }

    public static void AddAlert(Alert alert)
    {
        Alerts alerts = LoadAlertsFromJson();
        alerts.Add(alert);
        SaveAlerts(alerts);
    }

    public static void SaveAlerts(Alerts alerts)
    {
        string jsonString = JsonUtility.ToJson(alerts);
        //write this string to your file
    }
}
```